# Printing a list of objects

Tags: python

I am a Python newbie. I have this small problem. I want to print a list of objects but all it prints is some weird internal representation of object. I have even defined `__str__` method but still I am getting this weird output. What am I missing here?

```
class person(object):
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def __str__(self):
     return self.name + "(" + str(self.age) + ")"

def partition(coll, pred):
  left = []
  right = []
  for c in coll:
    if pred(c):
      left.append(c)
    else:
      right.append(c)
  return left, right


people = [
  person("Cheryl", 20),
  person("Shemoor", 14 ),
  person("Kimbala", 25),
  person("Sakharam", 8)
]

young_fellas, old_fellas = partition(people, lambda p : p.age < 18)
print(young_fellas)
print(old_fellas)
```

Please note that I know I can use either a `for` loop or a `map` function here. I am looking for something shorter and more idiomatic. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

One more question: Is the above code of mine Pythonic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you're explicitly converting to a `str`, it's the [`__repr__` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) that's used to render your objects.

See [Difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) for more details.

Comment: Thank you! Though you'll still have to wait for 8 minutes for the green cookie. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your made this object:

```
person("Cheryl", 20)
```

This means repr should be same after creation:

```
def __repr__(self):
 return 'person(%r,%r)' % (self.name,self.age)
```

Output becomes:

```
[person('Shemoor',14), person('Sakharam',8)]
[person('Cheryl',20), person('Kimbala',25)]
```

Comment: You are welcome. Nice function you have written, this partition. I am a string partition fan myself and I dig it.

Comment: ++: Comes with the bonus that the output can directly be fed back into python (what the idea of repr() is anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
print(map(str,young_fellas))
```

Comment: About the pythonic part, there's a section on that in the docs. You could use the repr(lib) to create your own debug representation. 
In this case person("name",1) is a better representation than person(name,1) because it should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object.

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0):

try overriding ***repr***

```
  def __repr__(self):
      return self.name + "(" + str(self.age) + ")"
```

Edit: Better way, Thanks to Paul.

```
  def __repr__(self):
     return "%s(%d)" % (self.name, self.age)
```

Comment: String interpolation `"%s(%d)" % (self.name, self.age)` or `''.join(list_of_string_bits)` are better styles to learn than adding up little bits of strings using '+'.

Comment: @Paul McGuire: in this particular case not really, so don't troll it :)